# How to make camera cover the whole screen

Tags: rendering, camera

How can i cover the whole screen because i want to make a render of the full room. I tried to do this with changing the resolution but at some point it stops[image]

Comment: Just pull the camera object back.  If needed you can adjust the clipping range to peer through walls

Comment: agree with @AllenSimpson, and you can also adjust "Camera" >> *Size*, and *Focal Depth*